# Establish the differential equation of SHM from energy conservation principle.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I really don't know where to start.
$$
\frac{1}{2} mv^2 + \frac{1}{2} kx^2 = E
$$
is the conservation of energy equation.

But how should I proceed and how will I get the differential equation of Simple Harmonic Motion (SHM) from that. Can somebody help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2 = E
$$
we know that $v = \frac{dx}{dt} = \dot{x}$ so we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x})^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2 = E
$$
take the derivative w.r.t $t$
$$
m\dot{x}\ddot{x} + kx\dot{x} = \dot{E} = 0
$$
zero arises from the conservation property.

so we can now factor out $\dot{x}$. This leads to
$$
m\dot{x}\left[\ddot{x} +\frac{k}{m}x\right] = 0
$$
Since $\dot{x}$ is not zero in general we require the terms within the brackets to be identically zero for the rhs to be true.
$$
\ddot{x} +\frac{k}{m}x = 0
$$
or SHM.

Comment: Clear and concise.  Well done.  +1

Comment: Minor pedantic point: you can factor whenever you want. You can only conclude that one factor when the other one is zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. But one question..does that dot above x defines dx/dt or something else. Please tell.

Comment: @AashishKumarShaw Yes, this is fairly standard notation in physics.

Comment: @Ian I think the point i was trying to make (which was lost from thought to fingertips) I just wanted to isolate the fact that we need the argument should be strictly zero always as opposed to $\dot{x}$ - In short, I see what you mean.